# What adhesive can I use to temporarily attach a tarp for flood control?

Tags: adhesive, caulking, flooding

Hurricane Ian dumped so much rain that our neighborhood was flooded by 9-inch-deep rainwater. By sheer luck, after 5 hours, the water stopped rising just 1/2 inch below our thresholds. I wonder if there is a removable rubber cement available in caulk gun cartridges that could enable me to temporarily glue 1-1/2 ft tarp strips to serve as waterproof temporary outside dams across doorway bottoms, slider bottoms and maybe even the garage door bottom to prevent rain flood incursion if another such hurricane comes through and/or slows or stalls. Suggestions & recommendations welcome - thanks!

Comment: Adhesives usually want clean dry surfaces to work well.  The removable ones have usually weak holding power.  water is heavy.  There are emergency flood barriers(not sand bags) that are suppose to work.  I think most of them are reusable also.

Comment: The question is moot. If you have water that high it's going to come in through the walls. They're not a boat. There are lots of little gaps, and if the flood lasts even a few hours you'll be floating.

Comment: @isherwood   It will depend if OP has openings/drops in their concrete foundation for windows/doors.

Comment: Fair, but that's an extremely rare scenario in my experience. Maybe it's more common in coastal areas.

Comment: @isherwood the best outcome is the house fills with water via several routes.  The worst outcome is the house keeps the water out, and indeed when it displaces more water than the house weighs, the house is a boat and will float away... and will land, not on a Wicked Witch but not on a proper foundation either. This lack of foundation will break the back of the house, ruining it entirely. See it all the time in hurricanes.

Comment: I'm sure there was a duplicate from some previous person not gasping what that much water will do, but I can't find it right now... Recommendation? Make like the 9th ward survivors and most new development in hurricane areas and have the house jacked up onto piers the water can run right through, without bothering it.

Answer (score 1):

Plumber putty

It is used to prevent water leaks

It can be molded by hand into a shape

It is sticky but it is not a glue so it can be relatively easy removed

Comment: Plumber's putty isn't very sticky. If anything, I'd say duct seal.

Comment: Plumbers putty is the best bet.  It seals but can be removed without much residual  clean up.  Kudo to Magaman and to you for getting ready for Hurricane season.    Remember after the putty is on use plastic  or a tarp then the sandbags.  It may not be 100% but will definitely slow water into your home slowly rising.  Storm surge  is another matter.

Answer (score 1):

You will need new names for things.

- Kitchen is now "Galley"
- Bathroom is now "Head"
- Bottom of house is now "HULL"

### Because now, your house *is a BOAT*

If your house's hull (bottom) is built to marine standards for a boat hull, it will remain watertight and keep the water out.  But if it's not, water is going to leak through every conceivable place, and enter the home anyway, regardless of your attempt at a barrier.  So if you have hull-grade construction, you're all set, right?

Not quite. Next we have to ask what your house *weighs*.  Because if your house is keeping out water, you have to think about how much water the house is displacing (how much could enter the house, but is being stopped from doing so).  **If the displaced water weighs more than the house, the house will float.**  Or try to float it, and destroy it trying.

So actually your best bet is move your stuff high and then let the water in, so you actively avoid becoming a boat... and then splash around in the ankle-deep water removing the bottom few feet of drywall so it dries out quickly when the water leaves. Leaving wet walls to mold and rot is the undoing of many houses.

### Okay, I'll admit it. My house is not a boat.

Now we're getting to the point I'm making.  Now how *long of a time period* will the water be 9" above your door sill?  If it's 5 seconds, you sold me.  That'll work.  **But if it's hours and hours... water is going to come in via every crack in your house that makes it "not a boat"**.

So here's the 99 GPM question: Where does the water *go*?  Does your slab foundation have drains all over it that lead to a *magically still functioning* storm drain system? Do you have bilge pumps actively removing water from a subfloor before it comes in and ruins your carpets? If you did, reducing inflow would help, because it would let the pumps/drains *keep up*.

But no such system exists, does it?  With nothing removing the water coming in from every "not a boat" imperfection, and with flood levels lasting for *hours*, time is on its side. The flood water will inevitably soak the interior and you're playing head games with yourself thinking any action you can do can stop it.  Other than good boat maintenance :)

### Get good at dealing with the inevitable.

I get where ruined floors, baseboards, drywall and furniture are frustrating.  I get where it feels like there oughta be SOMETHING you can do.  Well there is.  You can and should prepare for the
inevitable. Find out the worst-case water levels. Have shelving, attic access, plastic tubs for your possessions, means to get valuables off the floor, etc. etc.

When the water comes, know what to do to salvage the structure. Learn what the best practices are for building salvage and be *right there* doing it the moment it is possible, no delay. Run dehumidifiers. Lift carpet and clean it if able.   Speed is everything. What really ruins houses is when the houses sit there soggy wet for weeks or months while insurers bicker, trapped humidity and and rot runs amok, and by the time the remediaters make it to your house, it's all over but the shoutin'.

So be your own ServPro and be back doing it on day 1.  That way you remediate the damage while it's still cheap to fix, and you get to live in your house instead of your insurer buying you a new house--- hmm, on second thought, use your best judgment :)

Comment: @ Harper, Your assessment depends on many factors.  Most, yes not all, but most homes in Fla. are built on concrete slabs. Depending on the time of construction they may have anchoring features that tie all of the home together. This to be stronger against high winds, but it also has the benefit of being stronger against floor waters.  The OP is concerned, as many of us in Fla about the rising water from the heavy rain and the breakdown of runoff ability because of storm surge.

Comment: There is little threat of our homes floating away. However a backyard that can't drain anymore, while the rain is still coming  poses the threat of water infiltration and ruined, floors, baseboards, drywall and furniture.   We know there is little we can do against a wall of rushing water. However much damage from a hurricane comes from the areas away from the center of the storm, but inundated by the rainwater.  This is what the OP  was trying to guard against.

Comment: @RMDman Yeah, I really should have completed my thought there.

Comment: @ Harper,  Your new post contains better advice.  However often what is widespread is the loss of electric power.  Trees down so even ingress and egress for essential supplies is impossible to do unless on foot. This is assuming that anyplace is open and has any supplies available.  No air conditioning, no internet, water supply contaminated. cell phone unusable or spotty and no way to charge the phone if you can use it.  No gas if you can get your car out.  This can last for a few days to weeks. For some, months.

Comment: So sometimes we  just seek a place to get a good nights sleep and have a meal.  Starting recovery immediately is everyone's desire, but just surviving is often required.   I'm speaking from experience...been there, done that.

Comment: ...And I would be remiss to not mention that often within 24 hrs we see an army of responders from states hundreds to over a thousand miles away. To all the utility workers, first responders, linesmen, tree trimmers, and thousands of others who leave their own families  to show up with all the stuff we no longer have...A sincere and grateful Thank You.

Comment: @RMDman I would GTHO myself. I'm not accustomed to natural disasters giving 2 days advance notice lol, so I'd take it, yeah :)  Also staying without a car would suck but staying with a car destroys the car. I agree, I don't see any way to make such a place savable without *astonishing* levels of redundant solar arrays, batteries, pumps... much easier to modify the house to be easy to recover. Like all the modern construction where the 1st floor isn't much.

Comment: Sometimes there isn't any place to go.  During Irma I was without power in sarasota on the west coast of Fla. My son was without power in Daytona on the east coast.  Friends evacuated to Georgia...they lost power.    Before Ian we were planning to go south because it was projected to hit just north of Tampa. In the last 8 hours it turned south quickly and hit Fort Meyers.  The exact place we were going to evacuate to.  It isn't always an exact prediction, so you don't know exactly where to go. Friends went inland to Orlando and couldn't get back for a week.

Answer (score 0):

Doorway-filling DIY flood barriers.
I've seen these used in Venice, Italy & York, UK, but the houses are all brick/stone. idk how/if it would work with a wooden house [or has already been mentioned… boat]. This company are actually US-based by the looks of it & have several types of barrier system, big & small - https://www.flooddefensegroup.com/dam-easy-flood-barrier

[image]

In areas prone to river flooding, owners usually make sure the lower exterior is well tanked during the dry season, so only the standard entry points need this attention come flood season.
I don't know how this translates to hurricane season, I've never been anywhere near one.

In Venice, the city sets out elevated walkways, with local businesses filling the gap to their own properties.

[image] [image]